# find-file using ido as case sensitive

Tags: ido

I was using regular `find-file`, where when I type `D` and press tab it will consider case sensitive file names, such as `Driver.py` and ignore others such as `driver`.

I have enabled: `(ido-mode 1)`. I realize when I type `D` and press tab it also suggests `driver` and opens a complete suggestion window.

=> Is there any way to have ido to have same configuration as `find-file`, where case-sensitive is considered?

Answer (score 2):

Set `ido-case-fold` to `nil`

```
  -- User Option: ido-case-fold
     If the value of this user option is non-‘nil’, searching of buffer
     and file names should ignore case.
```

---

## update

Take care of:

- do not mistake the behavior of several options and how they affect the matching results, like case-fold, prefix matching and flexible matching.
- There can be a difference in how you set a variable which was defined using `defcustom` and `defvar`, sometimes it doesn't matter, but you can't assume that `setq` in a config file always will do the right thing.
- There is section in the manual which explains how the results are sorted. It might be opinionated, but it is documented and you can manipulate it.

Comment: It does not also do complete word search like when I type `en` it returns everything contains `e` or `n`

Comment: Check if it works properly with `emacs -Q`. Probably it's something getting in between, works as expected here.

Comment: Yes it seems the default behavior like when I press `e` and press `TAB` `TAB` it shows every file that contains `e`, but I want only one that start with `e`, it is possible to have it in ido as well?

Comment: Take a look at `ido-enable-flex-matching`, probably you'll want to set it to `nil` also take a look at prefix matching. C-h i m ido m matching

Comment: Please note this does not work if there is folders. When I type `D`; it first shows `driver` that is folder on my end and files that are starting with `D` are come later

Comment: please look up the manual *AND* your config, as with emacs -Q ido works as intended.

Comment: It does not work like original `find-file`. It always give priorty to folders no matter what by ignoring case sensetivity. I switch to `helm`.

Comment: I like `ido-mode` but not `ido-find-file`. I disable it in my init file: `(define-key (cdr ido-minor-mode-map-entry) [remap find-file] nil)`